# How to pass model values to WebApi url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to pass a View Model to Web API, I was trying to convert the View Model to Json format and query string, but it is not working.

I have the below model:

```
    public class User
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }
```

and the below View Model:

```
public class UserUpdateViewModel
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public bool MsjError { get; set; }
        public string FormStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

and the below Get method to get a user data:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int UserId)
        {
            UserUpdateViewModel vmUserUpdate = new UserUpdateViewModel();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiBaseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var parameterToAdd = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "UserId", UserId.ToString() } };
                var webApiBaseUrlFull = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(client.BaseAddress.ToString() + "User/GetUserById/UserId", parameterToAdd);
                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(webApiBaseUrlFull);

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                    {
                        vmUserUpdate.MsjError = true;
                        return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vmUserUpdate.User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response);
                        vmUserUpdate.MsjError = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(vmUserUpdate);
        }
```

Method User update:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UserUpdateViewModel vmUserUpdate)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                vmUserUpdate.FormStatus = "Error";
                return View(vmUserUpdate);
            }

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiBaseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //How to pass model to Web Api?
                var parameterToAdd = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "User", vmUserUpdate.User.ToString() } };
                var webApiBaseUrlFull = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(client.BaseAddress.ToString() + "User/UserUpdate", parameterToAdd);
                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(webApiBaseUrlFull);

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                    {
                        vmUserUpdate.MsjError = true;
                        return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vmUserUpdate.User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response);
                        vmUserUpdate.MsjError = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("List","User");
```

and Web API method:

```
[HttpPut(Name = "UserUpdate")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UserUpdate(User user)
        {
            await _userRepository.UserUpdate(user);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUserById), new { UserId = user.UserId }, user);
        }
```

how could I pass the UserUpdateViewModel vmUserUpdate.User to the Web API:

thank you and regards,

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: simple return the model ```[HttpPut(Name = "UserUpdate")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UserUpdate(User user)
        {
            await _userRepository.UserUpdate(user);
            return Ok(user)
        }```

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

simply return the model with status code OK for example `return Ok(response);`